# Why doesn't ServerSocket in Java agree with netstat -ant?

Tags: java

I wrote a simple Java method below to check if Port 21 is in use in Fedora Linux. It reported it is already in use.

```
protected static boolean isPortInUseTCP(final int port)
{
    Log.info("Checking TCP ports [" + port + "]", Verbosity.MEDIUM);

    // Checks to see if the port is available (not in use), otherwise drop
    // into the catch block if it is already used
    try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port))
    {
        ss.setReuseAddress(true);

        Log.info("Port number [" + port + "] not found via TCP port", Verbosity.MEDIUM);

        return false;
    }

    catch (IOException exc)
    {
        Log.info("Port number [" + port + "] found via TCP port", Verbosity.MEDIUM);
    }

    return true;
}
```

But when checking `netstat -ant` to see if it agrees with Java, it doesn't show up port 21 as in use? Why?
[image]

Comment: Please log your exceptions when they are caught, you simply forget them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java code doesn't show whether port `21` is in use or not. It shows whether you can listen on `21` or not. As `21` is a privileged port, the exception you're getting will probably complain of missing privileges.

Don't make assumptions about exceptions. Here you're completely ignoring one, assuming that it's about the port being in use and not about not having the required rights to listen on that port.

If you run your Java program as `root` (a bad idea), you should see that the port is not in use.

Comment: Yes, I expected to see that the port is not in use because netstat -ant is accurate. I have googled and I have seen many people doing the same logic as mine. What is the best way to check if the port is not in use rather than relying on the exception (probably false positive as you have mentioned) for the answer?

Comment: There's probably a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't actually run your program as `root`. You just need to give it appropriate privileges, if you do intend to use ports < 1024.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right Port 21 is a privileged port and the exception did complain - `java.net.BindException: Permission denied (Bind failed)`.

When I run the program in root, I got the right answer. It said the port is not in use. So my problem was that I didnt escalate myself to the right privilege in the first place. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.